# Iterate through array of arrays and pass coordinates to google map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, google-maps

In my Rails app I have google map that I want to display pins based on coordinates (latitude, longitude). I have dummy data in user.rb file as an array and I'm trying to map through it and pass coordinates to google map, however I'm missing something basic, because all works if I supply it manually. So how do I iterate so coordinates would be displayed on map?

```
#user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord

  COORDINATES = [[51.50853, -0.076132], [51.510357, -0.116773]]

  def self.latitude
    COORDINATES.map do |x|
      x[0] # How to pass coordinates correctly?
    end
  end

  def self.longitude
    COORDINATES.map do |x|
      x[-1] # How to pass coordinates correctly?
    end
  end
end
```

That's User controller index action:

```
def index
  @latitude = User.latitude
  @longitude = User.longitude
end
```

And that's index.html.erb. Here I provide @latitude and @longitude.

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
markers = handler.addMarkers([
  {
    "lat": <%= @latitude %>,
    "lng": <%= @longitude %>
  }
]);
});
```

Comment: please clarify for stupid people like me: So you want `markers = handler.addMarkers([{"lat": 51.50853, "lng": -0.076132}, {"lat": 51.510357, "lng": -0.116773}])`, right?

Comment: Yes, exatcly as you write

Comment: did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
markers = handler.addMarkers([
  <% User::COORDINATES.each.with_index do |geo,i| %>
  {
    "lat": <%= geo[0] %>,
    "lng": <%= geo[1] %>
  }
  <% if User::COORDINATES[i+1] %>,<% end %>
  <% end %>
]);
```